# How to find the summation fo all coefficients of a polynomial on this form

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How to find the summation of all coefficients of a polynomial on this form $$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n)^m$$

For Example: For m=2,n=1,a0=10,a1=3 the polynomial (10+3x)^2 = 100+9x2+60x so the sum of the coefficients = 100+9+60=169.

Comment: What are $a_0,a_1,m,n$?

Comment: I am sorry simple typo I am editing it now.

Comment: You should show some effort.

Comment: My answer shows why $169=(10+3)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all the terms are expanded, to get the sum of the coefficients you put
$x=1$ and evaluate. So just do that at the start and you get

$(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k)^m$.